# Attempt to write to field 'int android.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference

Tags: android-fragments

im trying to use fragments- changeing fragments with if and else.
i came cross with this error when im trying to run the program:

**"Attempt to write to field 'int android.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference"**

i search of answers and i saw that mybe the sulotion is to import the Fragmet.support.v4.app.Fragment

so tried that and i cant change to this import
what should i do or it other sulotion?

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if(isInSingleFrragment()){
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragmentB = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.FragmetB);
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.hide(fragmentB);
        ft.commit();

        Button switchbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.switchbutton);
        switchbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}

private boolean isInSingleFrragment() {

    View layout = findViewById(R.id.singleLayout);

    if (layout != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.switchbutton:
            switchFragments();
            break;
    }

}

private void switchFragments() {

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragmentA = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.FragmetA);
    Fragment fragmentB = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.FragmetB);

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    if(fragmentA.isVisible()){
        ft.hide(fragmentA);
        ft.show(fragmentB);
    }else {
        ft.hide(fragmentB);
        ft.show(fragmentA);
    }
    ft.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a check for null before hiding `fragmentB`

```
if(isInSingleFrragment()){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragmentB = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.FragmetB);
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (fragmentB != null) ft.hide(fragmentB);  // check != null
    ft.commit();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use hide ,you must have a fragment,used .add().hide(); the error tell you there ara no fragment